# Enable notifications at file level, when a change is checked-in in GITLAB

Tags: gitlab, git-push

we would like to get a mail notification, when ever there is a change in file that is checked-in to GITLAB.Currently under integrations we have option of Email on push , but its at project level/Repo level.I dont wan this notification for all check-in's , we want to limit to few important files.Can someone guide me , how to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a gitlab CI pipeline to email the changes, and configure it to run only when some specific files are changed.

Comment: Am a novice to gitlab, could if you have anything done previously in that way , can you share them if its possible.